# edit function only works for the first Doc in ReactJS, Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

so i have a table with various data and want edit functionality for every row (modal opens up on click of the edit button) - however when i have more than 1 entry, i can't edit the anything other than the first entry

here is my code

```
can you shorten this code for readability on stackoverflow

//import statements

const InternshipsWidget = () => {
  const [internships, setInternships] = useState([]);
  const internshipsCollectionRef = collection(db, "internships")
  const [newCompany, setNewCompany] = useState("");
  const [newField, setNewField] = useState("");
  const [newSetup, setNewSetup] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);

  //updated states
  const [updatedCompany, setUpdatedCompany] = useState()
  const [updatedField, setUpdatedField] = useState()
  const [updatedSetup, setUpdatedSetup] = useState()

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpenEdit = () => {
    setOpenEdit(true);
  };

  const handleCloseEdit = () => {
    setOpenEdit(false);
  };

  const deleteUser = async (id) => {
    const userDoc = doc(db, "internships", id);
    await deleteDoc(userDoc);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(internshipsCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      setInternships(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
      );
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const createUser = async () => {
    await addDoc(internshipsCollectionRef, { Company: newCompany, Field: newField, Setup: newSetup});
    });
  };
  
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

   const updateUser = async (id) => {
    const userDoc = doc(db, "internships", id);
    await updateDoc(userDoc, {Company: updatedCompany, Field: updatedField, Setup: updatedSetup});
  };

  return (
        <motion.Box>  
            <Box>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
              <Table aria-label="Calendar table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow >
                    <TableCell align="left">Company Name</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">Field</TableCell>
                    <TableCell colSpan={2} align="left">Work Setup</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {internships.map((internships) => (
                    <TableRow colSpan={5} key={internships.company}>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                        <Typography>{internships.Company}</Typography>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                        <Typography>{internships.Field}</Typography>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                        <Typography>{internships.Setup}</Typography>
                      </TableCell>
                      {user.isAdmin && (
                      <TableCell align="left">
                        <IconButton onClick={handleOpenEdit}><EditIcon/></IconButton>
                        <IconButton onClick={() => {deleteUser(internships.id)}}>
                          <DeleteIcon/>
                          </IconButton>

                          <Modal
                            closeAfterTransition
                            open={openEdit} 
                            onClose={handleCloseEdit}
                          >
                            <Fade in={openEdit}>
                              <Box>
                                <IconButton onClick={handleCloseEdit}
                                >
                                  <CloseRoundedIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                                <Stack>
                                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Company" variant="outlined" defaultValue={internships.Company} 
                                onChange={(event) => {setUpdatedCompany(event.target.value)
                                }}/>
                                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Field" variant="outlined" defaultValue={internships.Field} 
                                onChange={(event) => {setUpdatedField(event.target.value)
                                }}/>
                                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Work Setup" variant="outlined" defaultValue={internships.Setup} 
                                onChange={(event) => {setUpdatedSetup(event.target.value)
                                }}/>
                                <Button 
                                  variant="outlined" 
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    updateUser(internships.id);
                                    handleCloseEdit();
                                  }}
                                ><Typography p={1}>Update Company</Typography></Button>
                                </Stack>
                              </Box>
                            </Fade>
                          </Modal>
                      </TableCell>
                      )}
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
            </Box>
          </motion.Box>
    );
};

export default InternshipsWidget;
```

Tried editing the other entries, and only the first entry can be edited

Comment: You have to split out the modal and the open state into a separate component or else it will open the modal for every mapped element